# Pattern match (e.g /4947000219 in file01) & replace that digit with plus one in each file

Tags: perl

Searching a pattern (e.g /4947000219 in file01) & replacing that digit with one increment in each file.(e.g /4947000219 with /4947000220 in file02, /4947000221 in file 03..) same try with  20140924105028

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw/ ONE_MINUTE /;
use constant DATE_FORMAT => '%Y%m%d%H%M%S';

my $n;

my $directory = "/home/e/Doc/AutoMation";
opendir(DIR, $directory) or die "couldn't open $directory: $!\n";
my @files = readdir DIR;

foreach (@files) {

  open my $in_fh, '<', $_;
  my @lines = $_;
  close $in_fh;

  ++$n;
  $lines[0] =~ s/\/4947000219/\K(4947000219+)/$1 + $n / e;
  $lines[1] =~ s{:20140924105028\K(\d+)}{
    my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($1, DATE_FORMAT);
    ($tp + ONE_MINUTE * 2 * $n)->strftime(DATE_FORMAT);
  }e;

  my $backup = "$_.backup";
  unlink $backup if -f $backup;
  rename $_, $backup;

  open my $out_fh, '>', $_;
  print $out_fh @lines;
  close $out_fh;
}

closedir DIR;
```

Getting Error message:

```
Unrecognized escape \K passed through at /home/e/Doc/AutoMation line 27.
Scalar found where operator expected at /home/e/Doc/AutoMation.pl line 27, near "s/\/4947000219/\K(4947000219+)/$1"
syntax error at /home/e/Doc/AutoMation.pl line 27, near "s/\/4947000219/\K(4947000219+)/$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in this line:

```
$lines[0] =~ s/\/4947000219/\K(4947000219+)/$1+$n/e;
#                          ││              │└─────── Syntax error
#                          ││              └──────── End of substitution string
#                          │└─────────────────────── \K is regex only, warning
#                          └──────────────────────── Not escaped, end of regex
```

You haven't escaped all the `/` in your regex. This is why you get a syntax error. I'd advise you to try to find a delimiter that doesn't occur in your regex, like this:

```
$lines[0] =~ s~/4947000219/\K(4947000219+)~$1+$n~e
```

Also, your regex might not do what you want. The `+` after the `9` is oddly suspicious. I'd move it outside of the parens if there is a possibility of more than one occurrence of your number (now it is only quantifying the `9`).

**Edit**: Additionally reading from a filehandle is done with `<$fh>` and only in the special case of `while(<$fh>)` the contents get assigned to `$_`. Thus your `@lines` instantiation should look like this:

```
my @lines = <$in_fh>;
```

Comment: Done the changes as you suggest, but still issue persists. Now file have only file name: example:- file01.txt have file01.txt, file02.txt have file02.txt; Original contains are deleted.

Comment: already done the change my @lines = <$in_fh> with no effect. Still same result.                                       Use of uninitialized value $lines[0] in substitution (s///) at /home/e/Doc/AutoMation.pl line 27.                                                
Can't rename('.', '..backup'): Device or resource busy at /home/e/Doc/AutoMation.pl line 36 nor purpose solved.

Comment: when `$lines[0]` is undefined it probably means your file is empty. Also consider using `File::Find` it is a core module. I never have encountered the second warning, but I think it is some file system warning from linux. Furthermore, `readdir` includes `.` and `..` so you might want to add a `-f` check in your loop.

Comment: @Patrik :$lines[0] =~ s/4947000219/\K(4947000219+)~$1+$n~e;
  $lines[1] =~ s{:20140924105028\K(\d+)}{
    my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($1, DATE_FORMAT);
    ($tp + ONE_MINUTE * 2 * $n)->strftime(DATE_FORMAT);
  }e;

  open my $out_fh, '>', $_;
  print $out_fh @lines;
  close $out_fh;
}
closedir DIR;
getting Error :
Substitution replacement not terminated at /home/e/Doc/AutoMation.pl line 28. Seems issue with reg exp or Code Block:open my $out_fh, '>', $_;# not working properly.. also use File::Find with no effect.

Comment: You still get syntax errors. Check your line 28. And read the error messages, they really help. In [`perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) are all perl warnings and errors, use the search function in your browser on that page. And consider using the debugger by calling your script with `perl -d`. If you type `h`  you'll get a help with all the commands. Since your program is not that complex these might suffice: `n` executes the next line, `x` lets you examine variables `l` shows you the code that is about to be executed, `p` lets you print an expression and `q` exits.